# What is the advantage of using a pointer to a string instead of a string in Go

Tags: go, data-structures, structure

Reviewing some go code I came across this:

```
Person struct {
    Name *string `json:"name"`
}
```

and then some where I saw:

```
Animal struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

What is the advantage of the pointer here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` declares a [pointer type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types).  A pointer to a string is sometimes used when decoding JSON to distinguish the following JSON:

```
JSON        value of the Name field
{ }         nil
{name: ""}  pointer to ""
```

Without the pointer, it's not possible to distinguish a missing value from a blank value in the decoded result.

If the application does not need to make this distinction, then use the second form shown in the question. It's more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

`*` means pointer.
In your case, `Name` is a field of type pointer to string.

See http://www.golang-book.com/books/intro/8

Answer (score 1):

The `*` is a pointer.

> A pointer type denotes the set of all pointers to variables of a given
>   type, called the base type of the pointer. The value of an
>   uninitialized pointer is nil.

This is coming from the [Go Spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types). I would suggest reading it all.